# Updating Camel from 2.10.4 to 2.11.1 in ServiceMix 4.5.1

Tags: maven, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Recently I found article on same topic, but described solution doesn't works for me (with newest components).

Errors from ServiceMix (Karaf) console:

```
> feature:install camel-core/2.11.1
Error executing command: Can not resolve feature:
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   package:(&(package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
      camel-karaf-commands
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

camel-karaf-commands depends on a version of the OSGI framework not packaged with Servicemix 4.5.1 . You can attempt to install the required package from an org.osgi.core JAR but your mileage may vary.

Karaf 2.3 and 3.0 comes with the required package, but Servicemix 4.5 still uses Karaf 2.2